# FilesSearcher Program - Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have wrote a simple program which search in files for a specific text but I get this error:
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault`.

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong and can you also tell me how to use GDB debugger to get info about the error I get?

(With GDB I get this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555557612 in std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::size() const ()
```

But I don't know how get more info about the error, can you explain please?

## Code Test Program:

```
/**
 COMPILATION:
    g++ test_files_searcher.cpp -o files_searcher.out FilesSearcher_Linux/FilesSearcher.cpp FilesSearcher_Linux/FileContent.cpp
**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "FilesSearcher_Linux/FilesSearcher.h"

#define SIZE_SEARCH_MATRIX 0x6
#define SIZE_EXTS_ARRAY 0x1

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<std::string> matrix  = {"test\0", "lol\0", "asd\0", "lmao\0", "rotfl\0"};
    std::vector<std::string> exts = {"txt\0"};

    FilesSearcher fs = FilesSearcher(matrix, exts);

    const char *home_path = fs.get_home_path();
    cout << "[+] Home Path: " << home_path << endl;

    fs.parse_files(home_path);
    
    if(fs.get_found_files().size() > 0x0){
        for(FileContent *fc : fs.get_found_files()){
            std::cout << "file path == " << fc->get_path() << " file content == " << fc->get_content() << std::endl;
            delete fc;
        }
    }
}
```

## FilesSearcher.cpp:

```
#include "FilesSearcher.h"
    
FilesSearcher::FilesSearcher(std::vector<std::string> keywords, std::vector<std::string> extensions){
    mKeywords = keywords;
    mExtensions = extensions;
}

std::vector<FileContent*> &FilesSearcher::get_found_files(){
    return mFoundFiles;
}

const char * FilesSearcher::get_home_path(){
    const char *home = std::getenv(ENV_HOME);
    if(home == NULL){
        struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
        home = pw->pw_dir;
    }
    return home;
}

void FilesSearcher::parse_files(const char *base_path){
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir = opendir(base_path);

    if(dir == NULL){
        return;
    }
    int i = 0x0;
    while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(strcmp(PATH_THIS, entry->d_name) != 0x0 && strcmp(PATH_PARENT, entry->d_name) != 0x0){
            char *path = format_filepath(base_path, {entry->d_name});
            int type = is_regular_file_or_dir(path);
            if(type == IS_REGULAR_FILE){
                if(check_file_ext(path)){
                    search_file_content((const char *) path);
                }
            } else {
                parse_files((const char*) path);
            }
            free(path);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

void FilesSearcher::search_file_content(const char *file_path){
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file(file_path);
    if(file.is_open()){
        bool add = false;
        file.seekg(0x0, std::ios_base::end);
        int f_size = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0x0);
        char content[f_size];
        while(getline(file, line)){
            for(int i = 0x0; i < mKeywords.size(); i++){
                if(line.find(mKeywords[i]) != std::string::npos){
                    add = true;
                }
            }
            strcat(content, line.c_str());
        }
        file.close();
        if(add){
            FileContent *fc = new FileContent((char *) file_path, get_file_ext(get_last_relative_path(file_path)), content, f_size);
            mFoundFiles.push_back(fc);
        }
    }
}

int FilesSearcher::is_regular_file_or_dir(const char *path){
    struct stat path_stat;
    if(stat(path, &path_stat) != 0x0){
        return 0x0;
    }
    return S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode) == 0x1 ? IS_REGULAR_FILE :
            S_ISDIR(path_stat.st_mode) == 0x1 ? IS_DIRECTORY : 0x0;
}

char *FilesSearcher::format_filepath(const char *base_path, const std::initializer_list<char *> &args){
    char *path = new char[300];
    strcpy(path, base_path);
    for(char *p: args){
        if(path[strlen(path) - 0x1] != '/' && p[0x0] != '/'){
            char c = '/';
            strncat(path, &c, 0x1);
        } else if(path[strlen(path) - 0x1] == '/' && p[0x0] == '/'){
            char *temp = sub_array(p, 0x1, strlen(p));
            strcpy(p, temp);
            free(temp);
        }
        strcat(path, p);
        
    }
    return path;
}

char *FilesSearcher::get_file_ext(const char *file_path){
    return strrchr((char*) file_path, '.');
}

char *FilesSearcher::get_last_relative_path(const char *file_path){
    return strrchr((char *) file_path, '/');
}

bool FilesSearcher::check_file_ext(const char *file_path){
    char *rel = get_last_relative_path(file_path);
    if(rel != NULL){
        char *ext = get_file_ext(rel);
        if(ext != NULL){
            ext = sub_array((const char *) ext, 0x1, strlen(ext));
            for(int i = 0x0; i < mExtensions.size(); i++){
                if(strcasecmp(ext, mExtensions.at(i).c_str()) == 0x0){
                    free(ext);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            free(ext);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

char * FilesSearcher::sub_array(const char *arr, int start, int end){
    char *ret = new char[end - start];
    int index = 0x0;
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
        ret[index] = arr[i];
        index++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

## FilesSearcher.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "FileContent.h"

#define ENV_HOME    "HOME"
#define LINUX_BASE_DIR_PATH   "/"

#define IS_REGULAR_FILE 0x1
#define IS_DIRECTORY 0x2

#define PATH_THIS "."
#define PATH_PARENT ".."

class FilesSearcher {

    public:
        FilesSearcher(std::vector<std::string> keywords, std::vector<std::string> extensions);
        const char * get_home_path();
        void parse_files(const char *base_path);

        std::vector<FileContent*> &get_found_files();

    private:
        std::vector<std::string> mKeywords;
        std::vector<std::string> mExtensions;
        std::vector<FileContent*> mFoundFiles;

        void search_file_content(const char *file_path);
        int is_regular_file_or_dir(const char *path);
        char *format_filepath(const char *base, const std::initializer_list<char *> &rel);
        char *get_file_ext(const char *file_path);
        char *get_last_relative_path(const char *file_path);
        bool check_file_ext(const char *file_path);
        char *sub_array(const char* arr, int start, int end);
        void print_dir_entry_info(dirent *entry, int num_entry);

};
```

## FileContent.cpp:

```
#include "FileContent.h"

FileContent::FileContent(char *path, char *ext, char *content, int size){
    mPath = new char[1000];
    strcpy(mPath, path);
    mExt = ext;
    mContent = new char[size];
    strcpy(mContent, content);
    mSize = size;
}

FileContent::~FileContent(){
    delete mPath;
    delete mContent;
}

char *FileContent::get_path(){
    return mPath;
}

char *FileContent::get_ext(){
    return mExt;
}

char *FileContent::get_content(){
    return mContent;
}

int FileContent::get_size(){
    return mSize;
}
```

## FileContent.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class FileContent {
    
    private:
        char *mPath;
        char *mExt;
        char *mContent;
        int mSize;

    public:
        FileContent(char *path, char *ext, char *content, int size);
        ~FileContent();
        char *get_path();
        char *get_ext();
        char *get_content();
        int get_size();
};
```

Comment: With a quick look I see that `FilesSearcher::sub_array` doesn't nul terminate its string, which is a problem. There are also numerous memory leaks.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you for your answer, can you please better explain me where I need to null terminate the string and also the memory leaks you see? Thank you (:

Comment: What really might help your stability in the long run is to put ALL strings in std::string. You can construct these from char* returned by external functions too. E.g. replace void parse_files(const char *base_path); with parse_files(const std::string& base_path). The reference ensures no copy of the std::string is made so it won't be slow.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (`get_home_path()` used in the test program is not declared). It is also far from minimal: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your next step should be to determine which line of your code triggers the error, and what the values of your variables are at that point. Use gdb to get the call stack at the time of the crash, and work your way down until you find one of your functions listed. This should give you some idea of which parts of your code you can strip away for a [mre]. Do you need to search all files, or just the one file being processed at the time of the crash? Or did you not even get to the processing? Maybe you could get rid of the declaration, definition, and invocation of `FilesSearcher::parse_files()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't compile as posted.
2. You are mixing `new[]` and `free()`.
   Building your code with `-fsanitize=address` produces:

```
==1926539==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (operator new [] vs free) on 0x6030000000a0
    #0 0x7f641b887b6f in __interceptor_free ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:123
    #1 0x55a4e0211a4a in FilesSearcher::check_file_ext(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:118
    #2 0x55a4e0210baf in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:34
    #3 0x55a4e0216f6a in main test_files_searcher.cc:33
    #4 0x7f641b458d09 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #5 0x55a4e02104b9 in _start (a.out+0x34b9)

0x6030000000a0 is located 0 bytes inside of 23-byte region [0x6030000000a0,0x6030000000b7)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f641b8897a7 in operator new[](unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:102
    #1 0x55a4e0211a7b in FilesSearcher::sub_array(char const*, int, int) FilesSearcher.cc:125
    #2 0x55a4e02119bf in FilesSearcher::check_file_ext(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:111
    #3 0x55a4e0210baf in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:34
    #4 0x55a4e0216f6a in main test_files_searcher.cc:33
    #5 0x7f641b458d09 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
```

3. After replacing calls to `free()` with `delete[]`:

```
==1927190==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000113 at pc 0x7fbe6ef2ad54 bp 0x7ffc8f56c7a0 sp 0x7ffc8f56bf50
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000113 thread T0
    #0 0x7fbe6ef2ad53 in __interceptor_strcasecmp ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:511
    #1 0x562c2ffc8a30 in FilesSearcher::check_file_ext(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:113
    #2 0x562c2ffc7baf in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:34
    #3 0x562c2ffc7be7 in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:38
    #4 0x562c2ffc7be7 in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:38
    #5 0x562c2ffcdf8c in main test_files_searcher.cc:33
    #6 0x7fbe6eb1bd09 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #7 0x562c2ffc74b9 in _start (a.out+0x34b9)

0x602000000113 is located 0 bytes to the right of 3-byte region [0x602000000110,0x602000000113)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fbe6ef4c7a7 in operator new[](unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:102
    #1 0x562c2ffc8a9d in FilesSearcher::sub_array(char const*, int, int) FilesSearcher.cc:125
    #2 0x562c2ffc89d3 in FilesSearcher::check_file_ext(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:111
    #3 0x562c2ffc7baf in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:34
    #4 0x562c2ffc7be7 in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:38
    #5 0x562c2ffc7be7 in FilesSearcher::parse_files(char const*) FilesSearcher.cc:38
    #6 0x562c2ffcdf8c in main test_files_searcher.cc:33
    #7 0x7fbe6eb1bd09 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
```

This is because you don't `NUL`-terminate the strings you create in `sub_array`. Fixing that, finally produces a program which shows no AddressSanitizer errors, and doesn't crash.

TL;DR: use AddressSanitizer. Also, this program would be simpler if you used `std::string` instead of operating on C-style strings.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved by using std::string (: